# Global counter variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

im have a code that add and remove dynamically form controls. The add and delete methods works fine. But i like if exist only one control, not remove it.

I defined the next var, outside $(document).ready scope:

```
var Alumnos = {};
```

And initialize inside of $(document).ready:

```
// Valor inicial de casilleros renderizados.
Alumnos.count = 3;
```

The method that remove controls is:

```
// Elimina un bloque
$(document).on('click','.closable',function(){
    if(Alumnos.count > 1){
        var idRow = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
        var victim = $(idRow + " .row-fluid:last-child");
        victim.remove();

        var childs = $(idRow).children();
        if(childs.length === 0)
        {
            $(idRow).remove();
            $(this).remove();
            Alumnos.count -= 1;

        }
    }   
    console.log(Alumnos.count);
    return false;
});
```

The Alumnos.count value persist after delete. Any ideas ?

**UPDATE 1**

When the user click on "Add more", the code, create a form row with 3 controls, from a prototype.
Because, i cant use children count.
I need the user dont remove all controls.

Comment: move `Alumnos.count -= 1;` above `if(childs.length === 0)`

Comment: May be `if(childs.length === 0) condition` not gives `true`, can you create an online demo of your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have:

```
 if(Alumnos.count >= 1){  //Probably if there is only 1, it's erasable.  You had >
```

And move the decrement outside, like this:

```
    var childs = $(idRow).children();
    if(childs.length === 0)
    {
        $(idRow).remove();
        $(this).remove();            
    }
    Alumnos.count -= 1;  //This was moved
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: If OP wants to decrement count after removing the element idRow, then?

Comment: Probably, or probably when removing `victim`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your replies !! I found the way to control the elements remove with the childs count. May be isnt the best code, but works.

```
$(document).on('click','.closable',function(){

    // Get the id of the row.
    var dataToggle = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
    // Get the row
    var row = $(dataToggle);

    // if isnt first row (#id0), ok, remove all if you want.
    // if is first row (#id0) and have more than one child, happy remove ^^
    if((dataToggle === "#id0" && row.children().length > 1) || dataToggle !== "#id0"){

        // remove code...
    }   

    return false;
});
```